# Referencing a markdown file path in nodejs

Tags: node.js

My directory structure looks like:

> User/pcuser/sig/app.js

&

> User/pcuser/sig/markdown-md/description.md

I am trying to read the markdown file inside a const in app.js file. The 2 lines of code look like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const remediation = fs.readFileSync('./markdown-md/description.md', 'utf-8')
console.log(remediation)
```

I cannot use the absolute path and have to define a relative path for the markdown file. What is the best way to represent it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `..` to move up one directory to be at the same level as `/sig`. Using `./` means that the relative path is for stuff inside the directory where the script `app.js` is.

So instead of `'./markdown-md/description.md'` use `'../markdown-md/description.md'`